# matrix_world is transposed silently under the hood? Why?

Tags: matrix, numpy

I'm setting the `matrix_world` property of an object (from a numpy array) and I discovered that:

1. The last column (translation) is not set.
2. The matrix appears transposed

This is my pose matrix

```
array([[-0.02274943, -0.15741606,  0.9872703 , -5.47117027],
       [-0.90303298, -0.42049152, -0.08785396, -0.4303874 ],
       [ 0.42896842, -0.89353627, -0.13258596, -5.05977056],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
```

This is my output. Note that the translation component is not set, and that the rotation components are transposed.

```
>>> sel.matrix_world = pose
>>> bpy.context.view_layer.update()
>>> sel.matrix_world
Matrix(((-0.022749630734324455, -0.9030333161354065, 0.4289677143096924, 0.0),
        (-0.15741603076457977, -0.4204908013343811, -0.8935366272926331, 0.0),
        (0.9872702956199646, -0.08785402029752731, -0.13258591294288635, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

Is this intended behaviour or a bug??? I could not find any documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mathutils.Matrix](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Matrix) to create matrix properly:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
            
pose = Matrix([[-0.02274943, -0.15741606,  0.9872703 , -5.47117027],
       [-0.90303298, -0.42049152, -0.08785396, -0.4303874 ],
       [ 0.42896842, -0.89353627, -0.13258596, -5.05977056],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])    
            
       
sel = bpy.context.object

sel.matrix_world = pose
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
print(sel.matrix_world)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it's not possible to set the matrix from an ndarray, I still think an error should be thrown, instead of it being allowed with the transposition under the hood. Also, note that numpy is the de-facto standard for scientific computing and linear algebra library for python. Compatibility with Blender makes sense. Numpy comes bundled-in with Blender's python for a reason. I still think a few lines documenting this behaviour would be nice.

Comment: @Sergio  I think this has to do with implicit type conversion. You have to be prepared for "1"+"1" to equal "11", not 2